# python showing following error "unindent does not match any outer indentation level "

Tags: python, python-3.8

I write a following program to display the random color from list . i getting this error "unindent does not match any outer indentation level "

```
import random

colors = [ "white", "black", "red", "green", "Yellow", "purple", "grey "]
while True :
    color = colors [random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)]
    guess = input ("i'm thinking about a color , can you guress it :")
    while True:
         if (color == guess.lower()):
             break
        else:
             guess = input ("Nope. Try again :")

        print ( "you guessed it ! I was thinking about ", colour)

        play_again = input ("Let's play again T")
```

Comment: Look at the indentation of your `if` and `else`. They're one column different. They have to be the same.

Comment: Also, the line that says you guessed it shouldn't be in the loop at all. Getting the indentation right should be one of the first things you learn about Python.

Comment: last couple of month , I studying python language . meanwhile i working as system admin . I would like to know basic of python language . would you have any books or website link for references @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly observed when there is a mixup of `Tab` and `Space` characters while indenting Python code.
You can use either tab or spaces to indent a code block. Don't use both at a same time.
Your code needs to be like this

```
while True:
    if (color == guess.lower()):
        break
    else:
        guess = input ("Nope. Try again :")

    #some more
```

Comment: last couple of month , I studying python language . meanwhile i working as system admin . I would like to know basic of python language . would you have any books or website link for references

Comment: thanks @Python learner , its working .

Comment: @johnson There is very good tutorial material at python.org. That is the first place to look.